# Pandas: how to combine 2 tables and insert blank rows for missing values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine 2 tables (see screenshot) that share an order number column but confused how to approach it (very new to Python). I'd like to make a single table that has the order column and then list all 'types' for that order with their corresponding rates, and then the same for item&rate.

The problem is that some orders have more types than items so in that case we'd just Insert a blank row for whatever column is missing a value.

[image: tables]

So what I want to do is if one table has more rows for the same order than the other, insert blank cells into the other column. Here is the output I'm trying to get

[image]

This is my first experience with Pandas so any hint and recommendations would help.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.] Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Merge function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with parameter how='outer'

Let's assume that you have the first table in df1 and the second table in df2.

The command is:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='order', how='outer')
```

Comment: that merges the tables but it duplicates rows for every value. On the above example (1st screenshot, order 153), I get 4 rows total (all items from df2 for each df1 type). That's the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: @alexb Please try to use `indicator = False` or `validate = 'one_to_one'` options

Comment: the indicator = False option didn't seem to change anything and for the validate option I got "
MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in left dataset; not a one-to-many merge"